# Updating from 18.10 to 19/20

Tags: upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade from 18.10 to at least 19.04, using e.g. [instructions here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-19-04)
Whenever I type `do-release-upgrade` though, I get

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

I wonder what can be done at this juncture.

Comment: The best way is to install a supported release from scratch.

Comment: The tested upgrade path to 19.04 is gone, as 19.04 is end-of-life too.  You do need to fully-upgrade first; have you?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  Stick to LTS or *long-term-support* releases if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months, but I'd recommed re-install (without format) as it's far faster given you've missed the 19.04 upgrade path.

Comment: If your architecture was i386/x86, you should go back to 18.04 though; yes 19.04 also had support for x86/i386, but given it's EOL now that route has gone, and 19.10 doesn't have any.  fyi: 19/20?   Ubuntu releases for server/desktop use the *yy.mm* format and are *deb* based; the *yy* format releases are *snap* based and you cannot upgrade from one to another without re-install.

Comment: "The tested upgrade path to xx.xx  is gone" is arrogant: In a business env. you can not always upgrade as the developers would recommend. Preventing the necessary upgrade(!) is configured by software, I assume. Unfortunately I did not find out where. I'd really like to FORCE the upgrade anyways. My business to fix the issues.  If there is someone who can point me to the config setting that averts the upgrade - please let me know!

Comment: There are two upgrade paths, from LTS to LTS (which is the normal route for enterprise people), or via every release. 18.10 is on the every release path, and yes you can upgrade to 19.10 (once your system is fully-upgraded @opinion_no9) but it's on the user to deal with program/application issues given there will be a missed upgrade step (ie. a program may have made changes in how data is stored, which was corrected in the midway step). The fix was in the EOLUpgrades wiki page I've already provided (it's slower than re-install as already stated)